# How to import the jwt-decode type definition into Typescript (Ionic 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings

Just when I think I have the Typings in Typescript under control I come across something that proves the opposite.

This time I am trying to use the [jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode). I have installed the type definition via the command `typings i dt~jwt-decode --save`

Two problems

**1.** When I look into the `index.d.ts` I see the following

```
    declare module 'jwt-decode' {
        namespace JwtDecode {
        interface JwtDecodeStatic {
            (token: string): any;
        }
    }

    var jwtDecode: JwtDecode.JwtDecodeStatic;
    export = jwtDecode;
    export as namespace jwt_decode;
    }
```

The IDE (VS Code) is displaying an error *"[ts] Global module exports may only appear at top level"* under the last  line `export as namespace jwt_decode;`

**2.** How do I import this?

I try the import statement..

```
   import { ??  } from 'jwt-decode';
```

but I can't see anything to import.

None of the other (many) examples I can find seem to help. It must be simple, I just don't know the syntax.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[UPDATE]
After some more reading, it looks like typings has been superseded by just using npm..

So I tried

```
npm install --save jwt-decode
npm install --save @types/jwt-decode

// and import via
import * as JWT from 'jwt-decode';
```

But still can't get it to import correctly.

[UPDATE2]
I can add the statement `let t = jwt-decode("aaa");` and see the signature, but have the following IDE error

`[ts] 'jwt_decode' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

Comment: import * as JWT from 'jtw-decode'; in the last line should be `jwt-decode` is this a typo?

Comment: Ah yes was a typo. Fixed and added a little more info

Comment: these 3 worked for me

npm install --save jwt-decode
npm install --save @types/jwt-decode

// and import via
import * as JWT from 'jwt-decode';

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
npm install --save jwt-decode
npm install --save @types/jwt-decode

// and import via
import * as JWT from 'jwt-decode';

// use JWT() for decode. Not jwt-decode() !!
let t = JWT(token);
```

Comment: How to get the particular value from the jwt token. is it possible in angular. Above one is printing only object. I need to get the values from t. How we can acheive this.

Comment: the variable t has all the properties access to it like another object.

Comment: if you're expecting certain properties you can define `t: JWTPayload` and create an interface `JWTPayload` with all the properties on it that the decoded token has.